# New to R, receive an error in my function

Tags: r, function

```
x <- c(2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)

q<-function(x){
    bound<-quantile(x)
    iqr<-bound[4]-bound[2]
    return(c("Q1"=bound[2],"Q3"=bound[4],"iqr"=iqr))
}

T<-function(x){
  Q<-quartiles(x)
  min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3]  #outlier based on 25% quartiles 
  min_outlier
  max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 75% quartiles
  max_outlier
  x<-vector()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (max_outlier< x[i] || min_outlier>x[i]) {x[i]<-print("true")}
     else{x[i]<-print("false")}
    x<-append(x, x[i])
  i<-i+1
    }
  return(c(x))
}
  
 F(x)
```

#the output should be a vector of true or false.
get the Error in if (max_outlier < x[i] || min_outlier > x[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Comment: What is the `quartiles` function? Try not to use `q`, `T`, and `F` as function names.

Comment: quartiles<-function(x){
  bound<-quantile(x)
  MED<-median(x)
  k<-vector(mode="numeric")
  S<-vector(mode="numeric") 
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(x[i]<MED){
      k<-append(k, x[i]) # append or add values to k
      }
    else if(x[i]>MED){
      S<-append(S, x[i]) # append or add values to S
      }
  }
  iqr1<-c(median(S)-median(k)) # calculate interquartile range for x
  V<-c(bound[2],bound[4], "iqr"=iqr1)
  return(V)  
  }

Comment: `x <- vector()` is removing all the elements of `x`.